# Mass Edit Profiles - Enhanced List View - Inline Editing - "TOO MANY TO DISPLAY"

Tags: administration, profile, list-view, inlineeditsupport, enhancedlist

Any thoughts on mass editing Profiles, when you cannot use the Enhanced List view because the field list reports "**Too many to display, refine search criteria**".   This notice is not clickable / double-clickable.

*I tried removing entry "Custom" on the list as a test, but it just disappears when I remove it.*

---

**Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > Edit** (the list view)

[image: Sad]

---

I was not interested in a non-GUI solution (metadata upload, etc) if at all possible.  I am not seeing any solutios on AppExchange.

**The need**:  Mass edit many profiles at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to search for the field(s) you want to narrow down by. Use the Search box above the multi-select list. For example, if you type in Account, and click Find, you will then see things like Account: Modify All Data and Account: View.

[image: Finding Account Permissions]

**NOTE**: Accounts have been renamed in my org to Clients. As you can see, you need to use the label to find the correct permissions.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if this Search option appeared in the last 2 years or something, when I was doing less admin and more dev/BA duties.  In any case, Profile Details and User Permissions being selected shows their list;   Object Permissions does not BUT yes, the search works. Thanks.  Totally turned a blind eye to these fields even being there.  :-P  Thanks.  ;)  (14k+ custom fields across over 900 objects - thank you, Rootstock and Financial Force).